# RegEx for not allowing double quotes not working

Tags: javascript, angularjs, regex

I am trying to form a RegEx which will allow alphanumeric along with some special characters ( @-_. ). I have tried to whitelist these special characters, but other special characters are also allowed. So I have tried to blacklist all the other special characters excluding the above mentioned. Used this:

```
/^([^\s!#$%&'()*+\/:;<=>?\[\\\]^`{|}~,][a-zA-Z@._0-9-]*[^\s!#$%&'()*+\/:;<=>?\[\\\]^`{|}~,])$/
```

How to add for double quotes so that it is not allowed in the string anywhere.
Have tried \" but doesn't work.

Comment: Please provide the programming language / regex flavor and valid / invalid strings. Also, to be honest, your expression looks overly complicated.

Comment: Programming Language: AngularJS(using in ng-pattern).
Valid String: cathorse
Invalid String: "cathorse
Invalid String: cathorse"

Comment: Please edit the strings into your question.

Comment: Didnt understand

Comment: :) It became complicated because whitelisting only those specific special characters didn't work,other special characters also were getting allowed. So I had to forcefully blacklist all other special characters thus making it look complicated.

Comment: Verifiable examples?

Comment: HORSE  ---  This should match
"HORSE"  --- This should not be allowed

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I read you regex correct, and understand your wish:

```
^(                             # Start of string and capture group
[^\s!-,\/:-?\[\\\]^`{|}~,]     # Any character, BUT "blacklisted"
[\w@.-]*                       # Any number of word characters, @, . or -.
[^\s!-,\/:-?\[\\\]^`{|}~,]     # Any character, BUT "blacklisted"
)$
```

It's simplified by using ranges. E.g. in a character class, `!-,` is the same as `!"#$%&'()*+,`, which also *blacklists* the unwanted `"`.

Comment: Yes you understood it correctly, but the issue is, quotes areallowed at the starting and at the end even if I include it in the blacklisted group like this: 
\"

Comment: Please explain. [See this at regex101](https://regex101.com/r/opbwnv/3) (using PCRE to be able to have comments. The regex is still the same ;).

Comment: Thanks ClasG :), but it is not allowing single character now. For eg: a single character 'd'

Comment: So what's wrong with the single positive character class - `^[\w@.-]*$`. [See https://regex101.com/r/opbwnv/4/](https://regex101.com/r/opbwnv/4/)

Comment: Found the fix.

^(                             # Start of string and capture group
[^\s!-,\/:-?\[\\\]^`{|}~,]*     # Any character, BUT "blacklisted" 
[\w@.-]*                       # Any number of word characters, @, . or -.
[^\s!-,\/:-?\[\\\]^`{|}~,]     # Any character, BUT "blacklisted"
)$

We have to add a star for the first group so that single character is also allowed. :)

Comment: Clad to help. If you found this helpful, please up-vote. And if you consider it as an answer to your question, please mark it as such.

Comment: Voted :). This suffice my requirement

Comment: Actually you haven't. You up-vote by pressing the up-arrow left of the first line of an answer, and to, more importantly, mark an answer as accepted, you click the check-mark below the "vote-arrows". This is important because it help others with similar questions to find useful answers.

Comment: not eligible to upvote ,although answer I have accepted :)

Answer (score 1):

Use this one

```
Dim clean  as string = Regex.replace(tbname,"[^A-Za-z0-9\-/]","")
```

This one it blocks all special characters.

Comment: I need to allow four special characters( @, -, _, .)
1. at the rate
2. hyphen
3. underscore
4. full stop

Answer (score 0):

You can use your whitelist approach, but need to put the `-` last: **`[@_.-]`**; or escape it: **`[@\-_.]`**

Otherwise, `@-_` means "anything between ascii of `@` and ascii of `_`".

Regex101.com is gold for such things, it explains every part of the regex.